# Removing Big, old Files that do not belong in git

Tags: git

Long story short, there are very big files (like iso files-big) that were pushed into git. Not during my time with the group, but they've been treating the repo like an SVN-VC.

Anywho, how can i removed iso's from the repo and its history, to lighten the repo.

Or

Would it be easier to just move the code to a new repo, losing it's repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Long story short, there are very big files (like iso files-big) that were pushed into git**

You should use this tool to clean your repository history:

https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/

It is the perfect tool for this kind of task

> #### BFG Repo-Cleaner
>
> an alternative to git-filter-branch.
>
> The BFG is a simpler, faster alternative to git-filter-branch for cleansing **bad data** out of your Git repository history:
>
> - Removing Crazy Big Files
> - Removing Passwords, Credentials & other Private data

#### Examples (from the official site)

> In all these examples bfg is an alias for java -jar bfg.jar.

```
# Delete all files named 'id_rsa' or 'id_dsa' :
bfg --delete-files id_{dsa,rsa}  my-repo.git
```

[image]

---

After you have cleaned your repository use [this tool](https://git-lfs.github.com/) to store your large files.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Look at `git filter branch` and [BFG repo cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/), which was made precisely for this task. Beware that both of these tools rewrite history, which is a dangerous operation. Make sure you know what you are doing, and make backups before you do.